# How to update map data throug ajax

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to update map data through ajax but ist's not working here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function makeRequest(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo Url::base(true).'/users/online-peoples'; ?>",
            type:"POST",                
        })
        .done(function(result){             
            var icon1 = 'https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/onion/27-cabs.png&scale=1.0';
            if(result){                             
                var map;
                function initMap() {
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 12,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng('30.7333','76.7794'), 
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap']
                        }
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

                    var online =result; 
                    var mapIcons = ['https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/onion/27-cabs.png&scale=1.0'];
                    var person = {3:"Customer1 : ", 4:"Driver1 : "};
                    var arr = [];
                    var marker, i;
                    for (i = 0; i < online.length; i++) 
                    { 
                        console.log(online[i]);
                        arr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(online[i][0], online[i][0]));
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(online[i][0], online[i][1]),
                        icon:mapIcons[0],
                        suppressMarkers: true,
                        map: map
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(person[online[i][4]]+online[i][2]+', Phone : '+online[i][5]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i)); 
                }        
            }
        }               
    });
} 
setInterval(makeRequest, (10 * 1000));
});
```

The above code update map icons and date every 10 secondas but it's not working.Where i am doing wrong ?

This is my data :

```
[
    ["30.740395","76.7804482","Dbd Dbdhdh","1",4],
    ["30.740395","76.7804482","Sam Sam","1",4],
    ["30.7404344","76.7804032","Sumit Kumar","1",4],
    ["30.74041018","76.78060575","Chetan Nagrath","3",4],
    ["30.7403555","76.7804933","Sahil Kapoor","2",4],
    ["30.7403648","76.7805835","paras kumar",1,3]
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to give the url for any test data?

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your map. Since its inside **initMap** map function no one is calling it.

And there is no need to initialize every time when you got the data from the server. Just initialize once and use the same map object for your other works also.

And be careful while getting the data, You are trying to get the data in the index 5. But the *array has only 0 to 4*.

Try in the below fashion.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    function makeRequest() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "url",
            type : "POST",
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log("You Got your data", result);
            }
        });
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom : 12,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng('30.7333', '76.7794'),
        mapTypeControlOptions : {
            mapTypeIds : [ 'roadmap' ]
        }
    });
    setInterval(makeRequest, (10 * 1000));
});
```

Here you will get data after 10 second. If you want at the first time itself means call **makeRequest** after initialization of map once.